# A stick of length $1$ is broken $n$-times

Tags: probability, probability-theory, random-variables

I've seen this problem with other hypothesis (I think so) 
Anyone can give me a hint? Please.

A stick of length $1$ is broken at a uniformly  random point, one of these parts is preserved, this piece is broken again and the process is repeated successively to the resulting sticks.

My problem is:

Let $ \mathcal{X}_{n} $ the length of the resulting stick after it has been broken $n$ times, write $\mathcal{X}_{n}$ as the product of  random variables i.i.d.

I need this for calculate the $ \mathbb{E}(\mathcal{X}_{n})$

Anyone can give me a hand for find $\mathcal{X}_{n}$ as product of random variables i.i.d?

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1697946/a-stick-of-length-1-is-broken-in-a-random-place-that-is-u0-1-let-x-be-the-le

Comment: When you go to make the third break, can you break the piece that was not broken the second time?  I don't find it clear what you mean by repeating the process.  You could pick one of the three pieces to break the third time, or the one you didn't break the first time could be off to the side and you can only break one of the two pieces from the second break.

Comment: @Ross Millikan  no, you can't

Comment: No you can't what?

Comment: That should be edited into the question.  Also note that at the $n^{th}$ break you are holding two sticks, so have two lengths of sticks.  They must have the same distribution, but they will not be equal.

Answer (score 2):

The piece you select to break the second time has length distributed as a uniform distribution on $[0,1]$.  The piece you select the third time has a length that is the length of the piece from the second time times a uniform distribution on $[0,1]$, so is the product of two independent random variables that are uniform on $[0,1]$.  The piece you choose the $n^{th}$ time is the product of $n-1$ such random variables.  If you choose one of the pieces that result from the $n^{th}$ break it has a length the product of $n$ uniform random variables on $[0,1]$